# Products of Electrolysis of NaCl

Tags: electrolysis

I have gone online to see many times that the electrolysis of $\ce{NaCl}$ dissolved in water produces Lye: $$\ce{2NaCl + 2H2O -> 2NaOH + H2 + Cl2}$$ Other times $\ce{NaClO3}$ or some other compound. I just want to know with one solid answer (anyone), what does this reaction produce?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134780/ https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/127701/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one solid answer is that **everything** you've heard is right, given the appropriate conditions.

If the cathode and anode spaces are properly separated with a porous membrane or a salt bridge, then it is just like that:
$$\ce{2NaCl + 2H2O -> \underbrace{2NaOH + H2}_{cathode} + \underbrace{Cl2}_{anode}}$$
If they are not, then the products inevitably mix with each other and react further:
$$\ce{2NaOH + Cl2 -> NaCl + NaClO + H2O}$$
or, at elevated temperatures,
$$\ce{6NaOH + 3Cl2 -> 5NaCl + NaClO3 + 3H2O}$$
See, chemistry is diverse. Oh wait, and there are more options. Think of the [mercury cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_amalgam#Mercury_cell_electrolysis).